# Term for an unevenly aligned street intersection?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm searching for a way to describe a street intersection where the lanes do not line up directly parallel from one side to the other.  I.e., if you were to drive through the intersection and maintain your lane, you would have to veer a bit to one side as you crossed to be completely within the lane as you exited the intersection.  The vertical slope or grade isn't the focus, but the horizontal alignment of the lanes.

The term does not need to be a technical one.  The best I've been able to come up with so far is "staggered."  All lanes need not necessarily be uneven (in case that matters).

Thank you!

Comment: I'd call it a dogleg.

Comment: I usually call it a "jog".  (Or a "!@&# Moorhead intersection".)

Comment: It might be called "offset"

Comment: @StoneyB That's an answer.

Comment: @bib Not without more research to confirm it. I only call it a dogleg cause that's what my Mama called it.

Comment: @StoneyB [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dogleg) would agree

Comment: From what I can make out from the links in John B's answer, the US DOT would call 'dogleg intersections', *skewed*. It would seem the problem here is that it isn't far enough over to be called *staggered*; I'd say, "Watch out. The road **jogs a bit** after the intersection." Therefor I agree with Hot Licks (again, as usual) and there should probably also be some profanity involved when describing this poorly made intersection. PS @HotLicks - That's an answer, too.

Comment: Who downvoted this? Seems a perfectly logical and reasonable question to me. I have one of these a few hundred metres from my home, which I bike through to and from work/school every day, and I have no idea what I’d call it. _Dogleg_ is good, though. I’ll have to remember that. @Mazura The link in John’s answer actually has the audacity to claim that these intersections are _safer_ than regular ones. They clearly have never had to actually navigate them. Right nightmares for bicyclists they are!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lane is parallel, but offset, then it seems to be commonly referred to as a [Staggered Junction](http://www.drivingtesttips.biz/staggered-junction.html) or an [Offset T-Intersection](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/publications/research/safety/09060/006.cfm).

If the lane meets at the same point on both sides of the intersection, but at a different angle, then a commonly used phrase is *Skewed Intersection* (*oblique alignment* is rarely used)*.

<sub>*Edited to correct the statement that "oblique alignment" was commonly used; it's actually rather rare.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, John.  Staggered junction is exactly the situation I was trying to name.